# How to do user friendly text search?

Tags: search, full-text-search

I need to implement text search in database.

I am looking for general methods to implement text search able to handle misspellings. I am also looking for general methods to fine tune search for a specific synthetic language.

Comment: Currently, in MySQL I break the text into words, SOUNDEX each of them, concatenate them into another column and do a FULLTEXT search on that. It works quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene is one library that implements many useful algorithms including fuzzy search and auto correction. Fancy languages are dealt with by stemming the original words - that is cutting off any variable prefixes/suffixes to replace all forms of one word with one expression. This can be useful even without full analysis of morphology e.g. cutting off last 's' in English.